# I want to do a month name displayer

Tags: javascript

I made an HTML document with a button that when I click were to it display a prompt that modify a p tag.
Probably, I made a dumb error of code syntax(I am beginner in js).
Help me and explain please.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='calendar.css'/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function name(x){
    var x = prompt("Enter the month name","Ex. January");
    document.getElementById("month_name").innerHTML = x;
   }   
  </script>
  <title>:)</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="title_Month">
   <button onclick="name()" class="title" >Change the month displayed</button>
   <p id="month_name"></p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove x from name(x) and change function name, You shouldn't use name as function name

Comment: It worked to eliminate the function error but the paragraph aren't modified when I click in button.

Comment: I added answer which works u can check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name is reserved in javascript.

You should avoid using the name of JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='calendar.css'/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function names(){
    var x = prompt("Enter the month name","Ex. January");
    document.getElementById("month_name").innerHTML = x;
   }   
  </script>
  <title>:)</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="title_Month">
   <button onclick="names()" class="title" >Change the month displayed</button>
   <p id="month_name"></p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```